# Looking for a more elegant (correct) way of creating a formula

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, amsmath, stackengine

I wanted to achieve the following:

[image]

And I did but my code looks like it was in a major accident:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\begin{document}



\begin{flalign*}
    \setstackgap{L}{15pt}
    \Centerstack[r]{{\text{Something long }} {$\left[\text{Something}_{\text{else}}\right]$}} = & \text{ } \dfrac{\text{Something} * \left( \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} \right) } {\text{0,5} * \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} } & \\
    + & \text{ } \dfrac{\text{Something} * \left( \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} \right) } {\text{0,5} * \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} } &
\end{flalign*}      


\end{document}
```

I started using `flalign*` to get the formula aligned to the left. Then I posted a question here regarding lining up of the two lines on the left of the equation. That is where the `stackengine` package is coming from. When I had to put something in subscript it wouldn't compile anymore and I started fiddling around with the `$$` until it worked. I am using the `\text{ }` to get some spacing between the equal sign and the formula. The `&` in the end is used to actually align it to the left.

As I said. It works and produces the desired result. But as I will have a lot of formulas like this one, I wanted to know if there is a more correct or better way to achieve it.

**EDIT:**

I reduced the code for the MWE to only one line. As it was pointed out to me this was an undue simplification.

Comment: just use `fleqn` option on `\documentclass` and a normal `\[..\]` it's wrong to use a `align` for a single line display, a standard `\parbox` will vertically centre the text, so no packages are needed.

Comment: The formula has multiple lines. I reduced it to one for the MWE. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Note the fl in `flalign` is for full length, not flush left. the `fleqn` option is intended to flush left math layouts:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}


left aligned equation:
\begin{align*}
{\begin{array}{c}
\text{Something long}\\
{[\text{Something}_{\text{else}}]}
\end{array}} 
&= 
\frac{\text{Something} * ( \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)}) }
 {\text{0,5} * \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} }\\[\jot]
&\quad{}+ 
\frac{\text{Something} * ( \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)}) }
 {\text{0,5} * \sum \text{(Something)} + \sum \text{(Something)} } 
\end{align*}    


\end{document}
```

Comment: you could replace the `{c}` by `@{}c@{}` to remove the padding around the left hand array, but it looked a bit tight, so I left it in.

Comment: `\[ \begin{split} ... \end{split} \]` would work equally well here, and is perhaps a bit more logical.

Comment: I can't use '\setlength\mathindent{0pt}' because I want to have some other formula centered.

Comment: @Thomas it's a local setting you can set it just for that equation

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes